# Nullable columns not getting updated

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making an api using Flask. I set the image column to nullable = True, however I can't seem to update that column. Here's the code:

```
def register():
    try:
        '''
        different details are uploaded except profile_image which is set to nullable = True
        '''
        new_user = User(''' all columns are updated''')
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

    except:
        image = request.files['profile_image']
        user = User.query.filter_by('''query matched''').first()
        user.profile_image = image.read()
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({"message" : "Account successfully created"})

    return jsonify(''' json object sent''')
```

Here, although it should have been updated, the column remains null, as checked in the JAvascript based Database Editor (JADE). I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indentation for the code after except. Anything indented after except only gets executed if an exception happens.

```
except:

image = request.files['profile_image']
```

Comment: I am sorry if my code seems unclear, but the purpose here is to check for data like name, address, etc. and once it doesn&#39;t find that, an error is thrown, which brings the control to the except block. Thus, I will be sending data like name, address, etc in one post request, and a profile image in another request, which will then retrieve the user from the database and update the column.

Comment: @ShohanDuttaRoy Does it say "Account successfully created"?

Comment: Yes, and that is the mystery here. The code doesn&#39;t thrown an error, yet when I check in JADE, the column isn't updated.

Comment: @ShohanDuttaRoy Why not insert user data and image at the same time?

Comment: The other data will be sent as a json object, while the image will be sent separately

Comment: @ShohanDuttaRoy So back to my original answer. At least try it and see what happens.